# If $[A,B]=B$. Calculate $e^{iA}Be^{-iA}$

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, matrix-equations

If $[A,B]=B$. Calculate
\begin{equation*}
e^{iA}Be^{-iA}
\end{equation*}

From this, We know that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
e^{iA}Be^{-iA} = (\mathbb{I} + iA -\frac{1}{2}A^2+...)B(\mathbb{I}-iA+\frac{1}{2}A^2+...)) \\
= (B +iAB -\frac{1}{2}A^2B+...)(\mathbb{I}-iA+\frac{1}{2}A^2+...)\\
= B -iBA + \frac{BA^2}{2} +iAB + ABA + \frac{iABA^2}{2}-\frac{A^2B}{2}+\frac{iA^2BA}{2}-\frac{A^2BA^2}{4}+... \\
= B +iB + \frac{BA^2}{2} + ABA + \frac{iABA^2}{2}-\frac{A^2B}{2}+\frac{iA^2BA}{2}-\frac{A^2BA^2}{4}+...
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

From here, I'm not sure I'm going the right way.

Comment: If nothing else, maybe using the condition in form $AB=B^2A$ helps.

Comment: I suppose that $A,B$ are in the Lie algebra, so $[A,B]=B$ says that $AB-BA=B$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Good comment!

Comment: @Angel Can you precise what $[A,B]$ means?

Comment: Sure. $[A,B]=AB-BA$

Answer (score 2):

I assume that these are matrices with $[A,B] = AB - BA$.

**Hint:** Using the fact that $\frac d{dt} e^{tA} = Ae^{tA} = e^{tA}A$, verify that
$$
\frac d{dt} [e^{tA}Be^{-tA}] = e^{tA}[A,B]e^{-tA}
$$

Comment: Is the conclusion here that the solution is $e^i B$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. After all, $M(t) = e^{tA}Be^{-tA}$ solves the differential equation
$$
M'(t) = M(t), \quad M(0) = B
$$